# how to define many to many relationship in laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two master tables. i.e, `users` and `tasks`. Primary key column names are `in_user_id` for users table and `in_task_id` for tasks table.

There is relational table `users_tasks` (to see a task are assigned to which users and a user is assigned with which tasks). Foreign key columns are `in_task_id` and `in_worker_id` in users_tasks table.

I want to define relationship of users and tasks (**many-to-many**) into both models. I have read this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). But in my case, primary key column is **in_user_id** in users table. But foreign key column name is **in_worker_id** in users_tasks table.

So I don't know that how to handle fourth parameter in relationship function (`return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_tasks', 'in_task_id', ?);` **in Task Model** file). Either `in_user_id` or `in_worker_id` or something need to define more. If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Comment: try this $this->belongsToMany('App\User, 'users_tasks', 'in_worker_id ', 'in_user_id ');
params -> model, relation table, foreignkey, primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [laravel eloquent documentation on many-to-many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

In your case it would be :

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_tasks', 'in_task_id', 'in_worker_id');
```

Now this assumes a few things:

1. Your user and task model are working properly (since you have non-conventional identifiers you've defined them in your models).
2. Not sure if its still the case but in previous versions of Laravel, your pivot table (in this case `users_tasks`) also needs it's own identifier column, typically an auto-incremented id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> $this->belongsToMany('App\User, 'users_tasks', 'in_worker_id ',
>   'in_user_id ');

params -> model, relation table, foreignkey, primary key

And also relation tables should be in the alphabetical order. (best way)
It must be **tasks_users**

Comment: "must" and "best" are (in the very least) subjective.

Comment: @NandaKumar    I know that relational table name should be in alphabetic order. But I can't change name of any table or column.

Comment: @Akshay Vaghasiya 
 But I have not any option to change name of any table or column - not clear

Comment: OK, let me put it this way, going in alphabetical order is not the "best way" it is a way. There's no advantage in doing this neither in performance nor readability so it's just a convention. You either choose to stick to it (and the laravel  author suggests you do) or you don't stick to it, it's up to you and everyone else working on the project.

Comment: Please see edited question. I have mentioned that in which file, I'm defining relationship. i.e, `Task Model` file.